# What is the name of this greedy algorithm to solve NP-Hard Vertex Cover

Tags: graph-theory, vertex, greedy

I found this pseudocode in a textbook but I do not properly understand it, and it was poorly explained.

```
Algorithm 8: Greedy Vertex Cover Algorithm Example(G=(V,E))
1) C := ;.
2) while (E 6= ;)
• Select a node v of maximal degree in G.
• C := C [{v}.
• Remove all edges e from E that are covered by v,
i.e. for which e\v 6= ; holds.
3) Return C.
```

The algorithm is a greedy algorithm to solve the Vertex Cover problem. Does anyone recognize it and know it's name? I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: I think it's just called the greedy algorithm for vertex cover. You'd be amazed how many algorithms like these have no standardized names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find this particular algorithm on page 8 of this [Vertex Cover Problem presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/GajanandSharma1/vertex-cover-problem) provided by Gajanand Sharma.

It seems to be called Approx-Vertex-Cover also known as **Vertex Cover Approximation Algorithm**.

In the subsequent pages there is an example about the algorithm and how it works.

Also in [Approximation Algorithms: Vertex Cover document](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Eac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/wan-ba-scribe.pdf) at page 2 you can find another good explanation:

> Algorithm 1: Approx-Vertex-Cover(G)
>
> 1 `C←∅`
>
> 2 `while E 6= ∅`
>
> ```
>   pick any {u, v} ∈ E
>   C ← C ∪ {u, v}
>   delete all edges incident to either u or v
> ```
>
> `return C`

Comment: I've been glad to help you.